# launch tensorboard in colab

Tags: python, localhost, tensorboard, ngrok

i try launch tensorboard on colab, my code:

```
LOG_DIR = model_dir
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6060 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)

get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 6060 &')

! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

two days ago everything worked, but now such an error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPc3o.png)

Comment: You could try run tensorboard with the default port **6006** rather than _6060_.

Comment: Appears you're new to Stack Overflow, so just a friendly reminder to click the checkmark on answers to the benefit community members that helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

The error linked suggests the port you're using is `6006`, but the code example you gave above has the port as `6060`. So may just be a typo there.

It's also possible you want a TCP tunnel, not an HTTP tunnel.

In either case, might I suggest trying something like `pyngrok` to programmatically manage your `ngrok` tunnel for you? Full disclosure, I am the developer of it. [Here are the docs](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you're interest.